# Can I serve create-react-app assets from a relative path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Presently building my create-react-app build generates references to assets as absolute paths ie:

```
/static/js/main.12345.js
```

I want to serve from a variable subdirectory which could be:

/pre-prod or /prod

So setting "homepage" in package.json will not work as the homepage is dependent on the runtime environment.

I'd like to generate the asset references like so:

```
static/js/main.12345.js
```

And I'd prefer to do it without ejecting. Is that possible? I have looked at the docs and googled etc and do not see an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `"homepage"` in package.json to `"."`?  That's what I do.

Comment: Thats a great idea! Thanks!

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work any more, any idea why?