# GitHub Pages showing an empty page react

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've been trying to build my first github page for several weeks already. It shows an empty page and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong?
Here is my repository https://github.com/NatellaGomza/reactdnd/tree/gh-pages and page https://natellagomza.github.io/reactdnd/
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I serve create-react-app assets from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548374/can-i-serve-create-react-app-assets-from-a-relative-path)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548374/can-i-serve-create-react-app-assets-from-a-relative-path

Comment: thank you, guys. but haven't you seen that the suggested solution doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your `index.html`. There are scripts looking like this `<script defer="defer" src="/reactdnd/static/js/main.42b16ba6.js"></script>`.

As you can `src` starts with `/` which is not what you want with github pages, because your page is deployed to `https://natellagomza.github.io/reactdnd/` and not `https://natellagomza.github.io/`.

The solution depends on the bundler you are using.

I guess that you are using `create-react-app` so the simple change in `package.json` will do. Try adding `"homepage": "./"` and then build.

I personally use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/KonradLinkowski/4b2b825d2540c4eecfc5dc1f9e42a87f) that automatically builds and deploys my apps after each push to the main branch

Comment: Thank you! But the result is the same. I was using react create app